# Laptop Cannot Connect to Internet but iPod Touch Can?

Tags: networking, windows-vista, internet

I have Windows Vista and my laptop won't access the internet although it does connect to the wireless network. My iPod touch can access the internet via the same wireless network. Why might this happen?

Comment: What can you ping? the router? your DNS? google? Did you set a static IP or are you using DHCP (could be a DNS issue)? Can it connect if you plug it in to the router with a cable (could be a driver or configuration issue)? Also could be a firewall issue or something mis configured in the router (ip tables or such). Basically, we need more information.

Answer (score 1):

Since you can connect but not surf, I suspect the issue is coming from your AV suite or your firewall software.

To test this theory, disable them both temporarily and try to get online. If you can then surf, one of the apps will most likely need to be configured or updated.

Anecdotally, I have seen many machines unable to get online due to *an expired trial version of an AV program that came pre-installed* and that the user was unaware existed. Uninstall any AV program/s you are not using.

If these steps don't help, try pinging the router and then a name or IP on the Internet. Maybe you have issues with your wifi adapter.